# How to SVN merge branch1 to branch2 ? svn merge url1 url2 displays many changes, svn merge working copy does nothing?

Tags: svn, merge, branch

I want to merge branch1@2361 with branch2:

- Rev 2361 is last changed rev of branch1
- Rev 2472 is last changed rev of branch2

Both svn diff and svn merge commands between two branch URLs show *many* changes.  This is expected:

```
    svn diff http://acmeinc/svn/project1/branches/branch1@2361 \
             http://acmeinc/svn/project1/branches/branch2/

    svn merge --dry-run http://acmeinc/svn/project1/branches/branch1@2361 \
                        http://acmeinc/svn/project1/branches/branch2/
    Tree conflicts: 46
```

svn merge entered from working copy of /project1/branches/branch2/ displays no output?

```
    C:\working-copy\branch2>svn merge --dry-run -c 2361 \
                            http://acmeinc/svn/project1/branches/branch1/
```

I expected the working copy merge to display the same numerous differences seen when I used svn merge branch1Url branch2Url.  What am I failing to understand about SVN merge?

**svn info** from branch2 working directory displays:

```
    C:\working-copy\branch2>svn info
    Path: .
    Working Copy Root Path: C:\projects\tsr-mobile-obex-research
    URL: http://subsitedesign/svn/design/project1/branches/branch2
    Relative URL: ^/project1/branches/branch2
    Repository Root: http://acmeinc/svn/design
    Repository UUID: 53291536-067f-46a6-b3d1-4c270005dab3
    Revision: 2472
    Node Kind: directory
    Schedule: normal
    Last Changed Author: edward3
    Last Changed Rev: 2472
    Last Changed Date: 2015-08-25 13:51:29 -0500 (Tue, 25 Aug 2015)
```

[image]

I think the problem was I used the incorrect merge option "-c 2361".  I mistakenly assumed "-c" meant to use current revision.

The syntax of these two merge commands seem to output the number of changes I expected to see.

```
    C:\working-copy\branch2> svn merge --dry-run --reintegrate \
    http://acmeinc/svn/project1/branches/branch1/
or
    C:\working-copy\branch2>svn merge --dry-run --reintegrate \
    http://acmeinc/svn/project1/branches/branch1/@2361
    ...
    ...
    ...
    Summary of conflicts:
      Text conflicts: 8
      Tree conflicts: 2
```

RTFM. 
http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.merge.html

Thanks in advance,

-Ed

svn 1.8.5

Comment: Did you mean `svn merge --dry-run -c 2361 http://acmeinc/svn/project1/branches/branch1`? Since your in branch2 according to your path..

Comment: Thank you Ron.  I fixed the typo. svn merge entered from working copy of /project1/branches/branch2/ displays no output?

Comment: What does `svn info` return on C:\working-copy\branch2? `svn status` will tell you if you have any local uncommitted changes, are there any?

Comment: I added svn info of branch 2 to question.  Should I be merging a revision range?  Branch2 was copied from branch1 at rev 2329.  But I continued to bug fix on branch1 until 2361. Should I be merging a branch1 range ( -r 2329:2361 ) to branch2 ?

Comment: Your idea might clear up some of the tree conflicts... If all the local changes are checked in you can try to do this without the --dry-run. You could then use `svn revert` to go back to the original if you need to.

Comment: Thanks Ron.  I should not worry as svn revert makes it easy to start over.  I think my main problem is that I did not understand the svn merge "-c 2361" option correctly.  I think I will stick with the command line SVN commands for doing merges.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Ed. it sounds like you've found the answer to your question yourself. If so, do submit it as an answer to this question – answering your own questions, if appropriate, is useful, as it makes it clear what the solution to the solution was.